# FCM handling multiple device like facebook

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I am not able find the exact solution.

My scenario is like I have registered a user with one device and then user logged into other device with same username password.

When I am doing that push notification is sending data to only one device while other dont get any thing.

Other scenario is like I login with one user and then log out and next time I login with other user. and if I send push notification to user A form user B then my device i.e user B is getting notification . How can I clear the data.

I know there is a way . We are using backend server as PHP server for handling notifications.
How can I handle multiple login problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the different FCM tokens assigned to each of your users yourself.

There is no concept of "user" in the FCM stack, as far as I'm aware of. This "user" makes sense in your own business logic, and therefore needs to be maintained by you.